# Spring boot h2-console not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

Hello I am not able to open h2-console with spring boot

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RC1</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

SpringSecurity Cfg:

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN").and()
        .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {  
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
    .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
    .and()
        .csrf();
}
```

}

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class SpringBootWebSecureApplication {

```
@Bean
public Java8TimeDialect java8TimeDialect() {
    return new Java8TimeDialect();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebSecureApplication.class);
}
```

}

I am starting boot with:

```
-Dserver.port=8090
-Dspring.h2.console.enabled=true
-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
-Dspring.datasource.username=sa
-Dspring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

Logs:

```
2015-11-13 17:37:47 [restartedMain] DEBUG c.m.a.SpringBootWebSecureApplication - Running with Spring Boot v1.3.0.RC1, Spring v4.2.2.RELEASE
2015-11-13 17:37:49 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
2015-11-13 17:37:50 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
2015-11-13 17:37:51 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/h2-console/**'], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@11ffd6f0, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@615c57c5, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6b2cbcbf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@af7bece, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@17d03ab2, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@613197b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@8d48442, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7fa13240, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@9f16a1c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1f3f02ef, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@115de1f6]
```

But when I open browser with my app
console not appearing

```
http://localhost:8090/h2-console/
```

Any hints?

Thank you

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I think it's the Java8TimeDialect Bean, in your case.
 In my case, I have a DandelionDialect Bean and **when I remove it** the h2-console works again.... Try removing the Java8TimeDialect to see if the console works.
Something related with the spring boot DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration?, the order in which the servlets are created or mapped? Not really sure...

Answer (score 0):

http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

Answer (score 0):

You can try following configuration class:

```
import org.h2.server.web.WebServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import java.util.EnumSet;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    private static final String mapping = "/console/*";

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration(){
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean( new WebServlet());
        registrationBean.addUrlMappings(mapping);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter());
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
        registration.addUrlPatterns(mapping);
        return registration;
    }

}
```